# LEFT JOIN with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

With the next query I get two rows with data:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_cars tc
LEFT JOIN tab_countrys tco ON tc.id_cars = tco.id_cars
WHERE tc.id_cliente = 70
```

One of the row returns data regarding a Ferrari.
In this case I want a column with a list of Ferrari parts to be displayed in the same row.

Something like column ferrari_parts with values "part1, part2, part3".

If I do this last query separately I do this:

```
SELECT*,                        
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tlp.auto_parts) AS ferrari_parts                      
FROM tab_cars tc                        
LEFT JOIN tabs_join taj ON tc.parts_join = taj.parts_join                       
LEFT JOIN tab_list_parts tlp ON taj.id_list_parts = tlp.id_list_parts                       
WHERE tc.id_cliente = 70
AND tc.auto_parts = "ferrari"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to do the two operations **in a single query**, so that the two rows are returned with a column named ferrari_parts and is values

EDITED:

DB

```
|id | cars    | country | auto_parts
 1   Ford      USA        ford
 2   Ferrary   ITALY      ferrari
```

With the first query i get de same values.

I want to get de same two rows with ferrary-parts get form other tables:

```
 |id | cars    | country  |auto_parts | ferrary_parts
  1   Ford      USA         ford
  2   Ferrari   ITALY       ferrari   part1, part2, part3
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` whatever field(s) should distinguish the two rows you are expecting.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks. I edited my post.

Comment: @Uueerdo I'll experiment with GROUP BY.